# Laravel: whereNotIn not working as expect

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have an array with values 1,2. for example.

```
$arr = []

foreach($permission as $perm)
{
  $arr[] = $perm->permission
}

dd(implode(',',$arr));
result shows 1,2
```

but when i use the $arr in query its not working proper.
I am using this in following query

```
  $response = implode(',',$arr);
  $role = Role::whereNotIn('id',[$response])->get(); 
  //means select * from role where id not in (1,2);
```

but it works like below

```
 select * from role where id not in (1);
```

can you guys please help me to resolve this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing a string which is "1,2". You must pass an array not a string to the `whereNotIn()` method:

```
$role = Role::whereNotIn('id', $arr)->get();
```